# Register routes in area registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes in my area, one custom and one default fallback route, see below

```
        var dashboardRoute = new DashboardRoute(
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<PathResolver>(),
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<VirtualPathResolver>(),
            null);
        context.Routes.Add(dashboardRoute);

        context.Routes.MapRoute(
            "Dashboard_Default", // Route name
            "dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "pages", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "Dashboard" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

when I add both routes using context.Routes.Add/MapRoute the last route is not working, but when I use context.MapRoute on the last route it works but the GetVirtualPath in my custom route is not used for actionlinks. I thought that MapRoute was just an extension to context.Routes.Add? What is the best way to debug routes? I have used [Phil Haacks](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) route debug but it does not work with my custom route, is there any other way to debug routes?

I really need some help here.
My route registrations in my dashboard area looks like this -

```
        var dashboardRoute = new PagesRoute(
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<PathResolver>(),
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<VirtualPathResolver>(),
            null);
        context.Routes.Add("Dashboard", dashboardRoute);

        context.MapRoute(
            "Dashboard_default",
            "dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "dashboard", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The PageRoute is a custom route and you can find the code here http://bit.ly/er6HPn
With this routes active a link like this works great Html.ActionLink("Manage Roles", "manageroles", "account") but when I have a link that should work with my custom route like this Html.ActionLink(page.MetaData.Name, "edit", "pages", new { document = page },null) the result is http://stormbreaker.local/dashboard/pages/edit?document=Stormbreaker.Example.Models.Page, this means that GetVirtualPath in my PageRoute is never used. Can anyone explain to me way and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it, If you register a custom RouteBase instance in the RouteCollection object, [IRouteWithArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iroutewitharea%28VS.100%29.aspx) interface lets you associate that RouteBase instance with an area