# ASP.NET MVC 3 Areas - Can't Find View With Custom Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've got a custom route in an area as follows:

```
context.Routes.Add(
                "SearchIndex - By Location - USA",
                new CountryTypeSpecificRoute(
                    CountryType.UnitedStates,
                    "search/{locationType}-in-{query}",
                    new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", query = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new { locationType = new UsaLocationSearchRouteConstraint() })
            );
```

Example URL:

> /search/neighborhoods-in-new-york-city

Resolves the action fine. But it can't find the View.

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/Search/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

The view lives in **~/Areas/Search/Views/Search/Index.cshtml**

Why didn't it look there?

If i do`context.MapRoute` instead of `context.Routes.Add`, it works. So it seems like it's got to do with the fact i'm using a custom route?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831083/321946)

I made my custom route implement `IRouteWithArea` (take it in in the ctor), and update my registration accordingly:

```
context.Routes.Add(
                "SearchIndex - By Location - USA",
                new CountryTypeSpecificRoute(
                    CountryType.UnitedStates,
                    "search/{locationType}-in-{query}",
                    new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", query = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new { locationType = new UsaLocationSearchRouteConstraint() },
                    "Search")
            );
```

Note the last parameter "Search" - for the area name.

Don't know how that works, but it does. Guess the internal routing engine looks for routes that implement `IRouteWithArea`.

Problem solved!

Comment: That is awesome! I just stumbled upon this not even looking for this solution...but I've run into this a number of times!